# ClassCastException in getGroupView()

Tags: android, classcastexception

I am using [parallax scroll](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) which was running fine when the items were text. Then After that I want the 0th item of the list to be a ImageView so I added a condition `if(groupPosition ==0 )` in `getGroupView()`  which was working as expected, then I want to place a spinner below imageview so I added a second condition `if(groupPosition ==1 )` which is giving me this exception during scrolling. Rest all of my code is same

```
10-22 22:52:23.459: E/InputEventReceiver(31336): Exception dispatching input event.
10-22 22:52:23.469: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at com.vivekwarde.chalisaaartistutisangraha.CustomExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(CustomExpandableListAdapter.java:150)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2260)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5045)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3202)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3476)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)    
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1934)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1388)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1882)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3174)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3119)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4157)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4136)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4228)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-22 22:52:23.499: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 22:52:23.499: W/dalvikvm(31336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bdf450)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at com.vivekwarde.chalisaaartistutisangraha.CustomExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(CustomExpandableListAdapter.java:150)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2260)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5045)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3202)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3476)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1934)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1388)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1882)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3174)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3119)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4157)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4136)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4228)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-22 22:52:23.509: E/AndroidRuntime(31336):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the code, I don't know what is causing the problem

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if(groupPosition ==0 )
    {       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        if (imageView == null)
            imageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_big, null);
        //imageView.setImageDrawable();
        return imageView;
    }
    if(groupPosition==1)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) convertView;
            if (spinner == null)
                spinner = (Spinner) inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
            //imageView.setImageDrawable();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Android");
            list.add("Java");
            list.add("Spinner Data");
            list.add("Spinner Adapter");
            list.add("Spinner Example");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                         (myContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                         (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            return spinner;

    }
    else
    {
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;// line 150 : exception after scrolling when spinner view is gone

    if (textView == null)
        textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition));
    return textView;
    }
}
```

**Spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt" >


</Spinner>
```

I am trying it from last 1 hour, but dont know how to solve it.

Help !!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

The problem is that you are casting the `convertView` as a `TextView`!, you don´t have any `TextView` inside your `Spinner.xml`

```
 TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;// line 150 : exception after scrolling when spinner view is gone
```

Comment: but the same did not happen with imageview